# Draw "inverted V" function with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I came across an issue when trying to replicate drawing functions with `ggplot`. I have two functions, defined as follows:

```
GetMse <- function(x) 1 - max(x, 1 - x)
GetGini <- function(x) 2 * x * (1 - x)
```

Using default plotting system in R the figure looks like:

[image: figure-1]

Now the problem occurs with `ggplot`: the red function in Figure 1 is plotted as straight line on Figure 2.

[image]

Any idea or pointer? The `ggplot` code is pasted below.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0.00001, 0.99999)), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun = GetGini, geom = "line") +
    stat_function(fun = GetMse, geom = "line", colour = "red")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetGini` returns a vector but `GetMse` returns a scalar, fix `GetMse` by using `pmax`.